# how to write inline js event handler code in the react component using "this"

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a html code which I get to re-write in jsx

```
<div id="parent">                      
    <div id="child" onclick="this.parentElement.style.background = 'orange';">                          
        <img src="img/img2.png"></img>
    </div>
</div>;
```

Here, In jsx, `this` refers react component. However, in the above html code, `this` refers `#child`.

Can anyone tell me how to write the onclick code of `#child` in jsx without writing separate handler function but the same way its been written above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As i've found so far, *there are no way* to build React event as you describe, but i played around that and found some interesting things:

To change this line into JSX you have to replace you *onclick* event into *onClick*, then remove quotes from inline javascript and wrap it into figure brackets. So it should be something like this:

```
render: function() {
        return <div id="parent">                      
                  <input type='button' id="child" onClick={console.log(this)} value='Click Me'/>                
                </div>;
    }
```

But here is an issue it runs this event only once when your component mounted
[Here i leave a fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/21501/) where you can play with it.

***Update***

The answer yes you can write the inline event handler in JSX, as i told just wrap your code into figure brackets exmaple below and a [fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/21510/):

```
<input type='button' id="child" onClick={function(e){e.currentTarget.parentElement.style.background = 'red'; }} value='Click Me'/>
```

Thanks, i hope it will help you

Comment: Instead of writing a handler function, can we still change the parent element's style with inline approach? Thanks.

Comment: This is **not an inline event** listener, and will not work as a real one. This is a regular delegated React event handler.

Answer (score 3):

to make Andrew's click handler inline:

```
onClick={function(e){e.currentTarget.parentElement.style.background = 'orange'; }}
```

Answer (score 1):

In click handler by default there is argument `event` where there is property `.currentTarget` which refers to element which was clicked

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    clickHandler: function (e) {
        e.currentTarget.parentElement.style.background = 'orange';  
    },

    render: function() {
        return <div id="parent">
            <div id="child" onClick={this.clickHandler}>
                <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5.gif" />
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/21499/)

also you can use `.refs` like this

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    clickHandler: function () {
        this.refs.parent.style.background = 'orange';   
    },

    render: function() {
        return <div id="parent" ref="parent">
            <div id="child" onClick={this.clickHandler}>
                <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5.gif" />
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/21500/)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to set an inline onClick handler.

You try to write it like so:

```
<button onClick={this.setState({"favorite": "cherries"})}>Click me</button>
```

But that code executes on render and in my experience will go into an infinite state loop.

I solved this issue by turning the inline statement into an inline function.

```
<button onClick={() => this.setState({"favorite": "cherries"})}>Click me</button>
```